# Unable to remove new line characters from string

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to parse the links from the strings in Python. I got the following string:

> Hair loss can be all-consuming. In todays video, I start by sharing some holistic practices I personally followed to combat hair loss, such as; changing my diet, reducing stress levels and changing hairstyles. I also share my long-term plan for the near future to com hair loss, such as; changing my diet, reducing stress levels and changing hairstyles. I also share my long-term plan for the near future to combat hair thinning and loss.\n\nFor 50% off your first order  - [https://link.manual.co/LUCA5010\n\nShop](https://link.manual.co/LUCA5010%5Cn%5CnShop) my favourite products (affiliate) - [https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/lucasantangelo\nsay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/lucasantangelo%5Cnsay) hi over on instagram @lucazadeee / [https://www.instagram.com/lucazadeee/\nFor](https://www.instagram.com/lucazadeee/%5CnFor) business enquiries only: Lucasantangelo@hotmail.com\n\nLuca\nXXX\n\nvideo sponsored by manual.

First of all I removed the new line characters from the string using the code

```
text = " ".join(text.splitlines())
```

But I checked the results that it is not removing \n from the links and I am getting the following text after the above code is executed:

> Hair loss can be all-consuming. In todays video, I start by sharing some holistic practices I personally followed to combat hair loss, such as; changing my diet, reducing stress levels and changing hairstyles. I also share my long-term plan for the near future to combat hair thinning and loss.\n\nFor 50% off your first order  - [https://link.manual.co/LUCA5010\n\nShop](https://link.manual.co/LUCA5010%5Cn%5CnShop) my favourite products (affiliate) - [https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/lucasantangelo\nsay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/lucasantangelo%5Cnsay) hi over on instagram @lucazadeee / [https://www.instagram.com/lucazadeee/\nFor](https://www.instagram.com/lucazadeee/%5CnFor) business enquiries only: Lucasantangelo@hotmail.com\n\nLuca\nXXX\n\nvideo sponsored by manual.

Comment: Maybe `"\n"`s in the links are escaped. What exactly does `print(repr(text))` print?

Comment: Yes, they are not escaped as you can see from the resulting string

Comment: Try text = text.replace("\n", "')

Comment: print(repr(text)) prints the following: (showing the last part)
'I also share my long-term plan for the near future to combat hair thinning and loss.\\n\\nFor 50% off your first order  - https://link.manual.co/LUCA5010\\n\\nShop my favourite products (affiliate) - https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/lucasantangelo\\nsay hi over on instagram @lucazadeee / https://www.instagram.com/lucazadeee/\\nFor business enquiries only: Lucasantangelo@hotmail.com\\n\\nLuca\\nXXX\\n\\nvideo sponsored by manual.'

Comment: @AsadMajeed As you can see from `\\n` (note the double backslash), those are escaped. Try `text.replace('\\n', ' ')`, or `text.replace(r'\n', ' ')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your output from `print(repr(text))`

```
'I also share my long-term plan for the near future to combat hair thinning and loss.\\n\\nFor 50% off your first order - link.manual.co/LUCA5010\\n\\nShop my favourite products (affiliate) - amazon.co.uk/shop/https://www.amazon.co.uk/shop/lucasantangelo\\nsay hi over on instagram @lucazadeee / instagram.com/lucazadeee\\nFor business enquiries only: Lucasantangelo@hotmail.com\\n\\nLuca\\nXXX\\n\\nvideo sponsored by manual.'
```

suggests, `\\n` is escaped. So try: `text.replace('\\n', ' ')` instead, or using raw string, `text.replace(r'\n', ' ')`.